# using timer, Simpletimer or Timer_Three, Timer_Five as interrupt /Better solution?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to get the sketch running, but no luck yet.

I want to set pin high every 100ms,which are 5 full waves of 50hz AC power. And when is turned on I want to start 2nd timer to switch it off after 0-100ms. So I can catch 1-10 half waves with ssr Incl. Zero crossing...

Tried with SimpleTimer did not work

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

SimpleTimer mot_on;
SimpleTimer mot_off;
int MOTORspeed=50;
int timer_id;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(115200);
   pinMode(19, OUTPUT);
   mot_on.setInterval(1000, on);       // initialize timer1, and set a 100ms= 5 full waves=10% of full cycle

//   mot_off.setInterval(10, off);    // initialize timer
   timer_id=mot_off.setInterval(1000, off);
   Serial.println(timer_id);
}

void on()
{
  if (MOTORspeed>90)
  {
     mot_off.enable(0);
  }
  digitalWrite(19, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
}

void off()
{
   digitalWrite(19, LOW);   // Fire the TRIAC
   mot_off.disable(0);  //
}
```

unfortunately disable does not take affect! it does not disables enything...just running like mad :-)

```
void loop()
{
   int off_time=MOTORspeed/100;
   mot_off.setInterval(100*off_time, off); 
}
```

i tried with Timer3 and Timer 5... no luck either:
the skript does NOT STOP the Timer!!!

```
#include <TimerThree.h>
#include <TimerFive.h>

int MOTORspeed=50;
int timer_id;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(115200);
   pinMode(19, OUTPUT);

  Timer3.attachInterrupt(on);
  Timer3.initialize(100000);

  Timer5.attachInterrupt(off);
  Timer5.initialize(10000);
}

void on()
{
  if (MOTORspeed>90)
   {Timer5.start();}//
   Serial.println("ON");
   digitalWrite(19, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
}
void off()
{
   digitalWrite(19, LOW);   // Fire the TRIAC
   Serial.println("off");
   Timer5.stop();  //
}     
void loop()
{
  int off_time=MOTORspeed/100;
  Timer5.setPeriod(100*off_time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go, the answer !!!!
it is for all SSR with zero crossing function possible to change the speed in 10 steps (you can change it in the script to get up to 100000 :-) steps)

with SimpleTimer:

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

SimpleTimer mot_off;

volatile int i;               // Variable to use as a counter of dimming steps. It is volatile since it is passed between interrupts
int AC_pin = 19;                 // Output to Opto Triac

int mot_speed = 50;                  // in % Speed level (0-100)  0 = off, 100 = full speed
                                //1 Second = 1.000
int freqStep = 20;              // Means 20ms ONE FULL wave. Every 20ms we check if we should switch SSR off to get the right speed
                                //if speed is 50 (50%) we set Pin HIGH every 200ms, but after 5x calling Timer (i=50)Time = 100ms we set PIN low for next 5x calling of timer)
                                //if speed is 10 (10%) we set Pin HIGH every 200ms, but after 1x calling Timer (i=10)Time = 20ms we set PIN low for next 9x calling of timer)

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(115200);
   pinMode(AC_pin, OUTPUT);   
   mot_off.setInterval(freqStep, off_check);
}

void off_check() {

    if(i>mot_speed) 
    {                     
      digitalWrite(AC_pin, LOW);  // turn off SSR 
//      Serial.println("OFF");
//      Serial.println(i);                 
    } 
    else 
    {
      digitalWrite(AC_pin, HIGH);
//      Serial.println("ON");
//      Serial.println(i);           
    } 
    i+=10;  
    if (i>100) {i=0;}                                 
}

void loop()
{
  mot_off.run();
}
```

and with TimerOne:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>           // Avaiable from http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Timer1

volatile int i;               // Variable to use as a counter of dimming steps. It is volatile since it is passed between interrupts
int AC_pin = 19;              // Output to Opto Triac

int mot_speed = 50;           // in % Speed level (0-100)  0 = off, 100 = full speed

                                  //1 Second = 1.000.000
int freqStep = 20000;             // Means 20ms ONE FULL wave. Every 20ms we check if we should switch SSR off to get the right speed
                                  //if speed is 50 (50%) we set Pin HIGH every 200ms, but after 5x calling Timer (i=50)Time = 100ms we set PIN low for next 5x calling of timer)
                                  //if speed is 10 (10%) we set Pin HIGH every 200ms, but after 1x calling Timer (i=10)Time = 20ms we set PIN low for next 9x calling of timer)



void setup() {  // Begin setup
  Serial.begin(115200);   
  pinMode(AC_pin, OUTPUT);                          // Set the Triac pin as output
  Timer1.initialize(freqStep);                      // Initialize TimerOne library for the freq we need
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(off_check, freqStep);      // 
  // Use the TimerOne Library to attach an interrupt
}

void off_check() {

    if(i>mot_speed) 
    {                     
      digitalWrite(AC_pin, LOW);  // turn off SSR 
//      Serial.println("OFF");
//      Serial.println(i);                 
    } 
    else 
    {
      digitalWrite(AC_pin, HIGH);
//      Serial.println("ON");
//      Serial.println(i);           
    } 
    i+=5;  
    if (i>100) {i=0;}

}

void loop() 
{  

}
```